# Does anyone design api or library code in this way?

Tags: class, pseudocode, api-design, method-chaining

I was reading up some things about how to design a library or API well, and stumbled across Joshua Bloch's great talk at Google Tech Talks. Now although I am nowhere near a professional API developer, I think programming a bunch of classes/functions is a similar, although much scaled-down version of the same thing - clear-cut separation of actions, ease and pleasurable use, encouraging clean code, etc.

I was going through some widely used open source Java code and got this idea (nothing new, but just putting it up lucidly...)

Let us take an example **pseudo code** (or **maybe** some dialect of BASIC):

```
1. new label
2. set name 'hello world'
3. set color 'blue'
4. show 'topmost'
5. on click hide
```

Now inspired by the Java code I would want to be able to do **something** like this:

```
1. Label l = new Label()
2.          .setName('Hello World')
3.          .setColor('blue')
4.          .show(zindex.top);
5. l.onClick = l.hide() ;
```

My question is this:
Does anyone else design APIs starting from pseudo-code like this?

Is it a good idea for something small? Say upto 10 classes each with maybe 10 methods, each method not more than than 5-6 lines code inside it. That is obviously just a rough set of numbers to to show the size of the classes to be designed - nowhere close to a full API and not just a hobby project - *a professional package that does something small but does it well*.

Has anyone found any serious drawbacks to this approach?

I think the **one real benefit** is that it **forces you to write down your use-cases first**.

The other thing is that the **nouns and verbs stay simple**, enabling your final product to dodge the **MultiPhraseAbstractParadigmDesignPatternImplementor** syndrome :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly common design pattern called a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). It's common in functional languages and is gaining popularity elsewhere. I first saw it in Scheme.

It's a very convenient and readable idiom, but remember that there will often be times where you actually do want to initialize more than one variable in a single function call. For example, when there's internal state that has to be set depending on a combination of data, or when setting and overwriting default values is costly. So, as with all "patterns", use judiciously and with forethought.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery does exactly this. From http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/jquery-1-4-released-the-15-new-features-you-must-know/:

```
jQuery('<div/>', {  
    id: 'foo',  
    css: {  
        fontWeight: 700,  
        color: 'green'  
    },  
    click: function(){  
        alert('Foo has been clicked!');  
    }  
});
```

or for pre-1.4:

```
jQuery('<div/>')  
   .attr('id', 'foo')  
   .css({  
       fontWeight: 700,  
       color: 'green'  
   })  
   .click(function(){  
       alert('Foo has been clicked!');  
   });
```

I've also done similar things in C# generating WPF in code:

```
new StackPanel {
   Children = {
      new TextBlock { Text = "Hi there", Width = 50 },
      new TextBox { Width = 100 },
      new Border { 
          Content = new ListBox()
      }
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the way that jQuery is designed, it always ends up returning itself so that you can chain methods like this.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to start with empty classes and methods. Its really a question of top down vs bottom up design.

I really prefer a huge whiteboard sketch though.